# GLSL Build Errors

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I get these errors when i try to put together a GLSL example program from a website, just so i can get a feel for shaders. I also get these exact same errors when i try to implement this shader in my own program.

http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/glsl/1_setup.html#DL

```
>------ Build started: Project: TheLightingExperiment2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shader::init(char const *,char const *)" (?init@Shader@@QAEXPBD0@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl init(void)" (?init@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shader::unbind(void)" (?unbind@Shader@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shader::bind(void)" (?bind@Shader@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl display(void)" (?display@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Shader::Shader(void)" (??0Shader@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'shader''(void)" (??__Eshader@@YAXXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Shader::~Shader(void)" (??1Shader@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'shader''(void)" (??__Fshader@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\Shawn\Desktop\TheLightingExperiment2\Debug\TheLightingExperiment2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: did you use the Shader class used in the tutorial?

Comment: did you add the Shader.cpp file to your project (not just the same folder) as well?

Comment: I didn't, but now i did and got these new errors: __imp____glewLinkProgram
1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewAttachShader
1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateProgram
1>shader.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCompileShader

Comment: Did i solve the previous problem, or dig myself deeper?

Answer (score 1):

These are `undefined reference` errors. from the Linker.You didn't attach the libraries. as you are in Visual Studio you can do this by right clicking on your Solution and thenby going to Properties.

Comment: What libraries though? The shader doesn't have any libraries

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing libraries.  Look into GLEW the GL Extension Wrangler and link that into your project.  It is especially helpful with making shader extensions work.

[GLEW Page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)